# Airplane mode for a 2017 Ford Escape?

Tags: ford

Is there "airplane mode" for a 2017 Ford Escape with Sync?  I'm pretty new to cars with wifi and 3g (still not sure if the 3g requires a phone or a tower to use it), but the wifi just lists access points.  But with all the concern about cars with internet connections being hacked, I just wondered if there was an airplane mode somewhere on the car to turn all of that off.

I suppose this would include bluetooth as well, and any other wireless technology I may not have mentioned.

Comment: I get hassled over a slightly large carry-on and you want to take your car on the plane?!

Comment: @JPhi1618 No I wanted to make it fly!  heheh

Comment: it might be possible through software. what does the owners manual say? have you tried asking the dealer? as a last resort i suppose you could disconnect the wifi antenna.